# Calling the return value of a function to other function

Tags: javascript, function

How to properly return the value of the variable `otherURL` and call/use it in other function of the same file.

Using the code below.

```
function getOtherURL() {
    var url = "https://url/data.json";

    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', data);
        let otherURL;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //some code
            otherURL = "http://url/from" + from + "&to=" + to;
        }
        console.log("otherURL" , otherURL);
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err });
}
```

This is my other function

```
export function getData() {
    //need to read the value of otherURL and assign into new variable something like this
    let newURL = otherURL;
    const promiseMSFT = fetch(newURL) //here I want to assign the newURL
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
    //more code

}
```

Comment: `getOtherURL().then(.....` or `async / await`  but in both cases you need to return your fetch.

Comment: im interested in your `getOtherURL().then(....`, can you please complete that? Thanks!

Comment: How would you call a value?

Comment: Btw. `.catch(err => { throw err });` your can remove this, it has no use..

Comment: Can you modify the `getData()` function to have a parameter ?

Comment: @VuHuuCuong id modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getOtherURL() {
  var url = "https://url/data.json";
  return fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', data);
    let otherURL;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //some code
      otherURL = "http://url/from" + from + "&to=" + to;
    }
    return otherUrl; //return value
  })
  .catch(err => { throw err });
}
```

and then call it in your exported function

```
export function getData() {
    //return promise to the caller
    return getOtherURL().then(otherUrl => {
      let newURL = otherURL;
      //then you can chain the other promise
      return fetch(newUrl);
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       //more code
     })

}
```

Comment: Your answer is working in me. Thank you so much Karim! :)

Comment: one thing I think we are missing is how can I get the `newURL` outside of `getOtherURL().then...`? since I need to use it in `const promiseMSFT = fetch(newURL)`

Comment: check the answer i've added the last promise

Comment: that did it. Thanks again! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `getData()` function to have a parameter like `getData(otherURL)`, you can do this:

```
function getOtherURL() {
      const url = 'https://url/data.json';

      fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', data);
      let otherURL;

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // some code
        otherURL = `http://url/from${from}&to=${to}`;
      }
      console.log('otherURL', otherURL);
      return otherURL;
    })
    .then(otherURL => {
    // chain then() here
      getData(otherURL);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Modified function

```
export function getData(otherURL) {
  // need to read the value of otherURL and assign into new variable something like this
  let newURL = otherURL;
  console.log(newURL);
}
```

Comment: This gives me `undefined` result in the console log.